# Хранение простых данных. Как лучше?

Tags: структуры-данных, база-данных

Добрый день! Динамически получаю данные статистики с внешнего сайта. Получаемые данные не большие: url, дата и количество просмотров. Данные запрашиваются ежедневно и все время будут копиться.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше организовать структуру базы данных для хранения такой информации и в каком виде их желательно ее хранить.

Спасибо.

Comment: Создаем реляционную ДБ с тремя полями: url, дата и количество просмотров. Далее можно подумать о нормализации этой базы.

Comment: Надысь бы еще и первичный ключ добавить, не забыть проиндексировать по полям url и дате - наверняка будут писать отчеты.

Comment: Если не будет связываться внешняя таблица, то можно и без первичного ключа. А индексирование не помешает.

Answer (score 1):

А цель сбора и какая потом отчетность понадобится уточните сразу, если история ненужна - то у вас 1 таблица так и останется, если нет - то нада как минимум 2 - в одной только адреса, а во второй храним id адреса, дата снятия показателля ну и сам показатель - кол-во просмотров